# Sass: alternative variable in less

Tags: css, sass, less

Tell me, please:

In *less* file I have variables:

```
@example-1-top:                        value;
@example-1-bottom:                     value;
```

And I called in Mixins, depending on the argument:

```
.example(@depth) when (@example-browser-prefix = false) {
  box-shadow: ~"@{example-@{depth}-bottom}, @{example-@{depth}-top}";
}
```

In *sass* file, I have variables:

```
$example-1-top:                        value;
$example-1-bottom:                     value;
```

And I called in Mixins, depending on the argument:

```
@mixin z-depth($depth) {
  $depth: ???;
  @include prefixer(box-shadow, $depth, webkit moz spec);
}
```

Instead of `???` I tried:

```
#{$example-#{$depth}-top}, #{$example-#{$depth}-bottom}
$example-#{$depth}-top, $example-#{$depth}-bottom
```

And...

```
Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$example-".
```

The rest returns a string.

Teach please wisdom :)

Comment: You mean *Sass* in your title: *SCCS* was an old version control system on Unix in the 1990s

Comment: Do you need a $example variable in your .scss file? You have to use .example instead of $example